# strategy to move funds between international accounts

Tags: mutual-funds, international-transfer, transfer, online-brokerage, japan

I need to transfer funds from my German funds portfolio to an international broker.
Most of my assets are in the profitable zone now. Only two are negative currently.

I wondered which strategy might be the best for moving them:

- sell all assets (and buy them or others again in a new account)
- move all of them to an international broker
- move only the negative assets and sell all the others
- [do something completely different]

I'm not really sure which strategy is the most logical one.
I only know that my new account would likely be in the US (interactive b...) and I don't really like the thought much.
But seems getting an account here (Japan) is troublesome.

Comment: Transfer of assets between brokers is standard procedure with just very minor paperwork.

So, it all runs down what you WANT - i.e. investment strategy. And that is not your question, so there is nothing left.

Comment: Not at all true I think. There's fees and the possibility of false start value rating resulting in much higher taxes. And that's just what I know of.

Comment: Yeah, but unless you mvoe funds daily fees here are a joke and false start values are something to document. Noone says this is a problem for people not used to keep their paperwork in order.